# Is it possible to purchase durable product whenever user reinstall App?

Tags: windows-phone-8

User can purchase durable product from my app. If he uninstalled my app and then reinstall and he will lose all purchased information. Now if he want to buy it again, how is it possible? if possible, how to implement it???

Answer (score 0):

All windows phone real money products should be WP App Store purchases. If it is not a real money product you can sync purchases via internet. It is not possible to keep any information locally between the two installations of the application.

Comment: my app only store locally which product is purchased. After re-instillation i need to make user buy it again.

Comment: @SuzanHaque _It is not possible to keep any information locally between the two installations of the application._ and _you can sync purchases via internet_ and if they are in app store purchases there is api call to get all purchased items.